# android fragment interface nullpointerexception

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, interface, nullpointerexception

I have two fragments and I want to update second fragment `TextView` from first fragment. I desided to use `interface`

```
public interface LogTextUpdater {
    void updateText(Information info);
}
```

Here's my first fragment

```
public class UiFragment extends Fragment {
    public LogTextUpdater log;
    ...
    ...
    private void setInformationObject(String message){
        Information info = null;
        try {
            info = new XmlParser(message).get();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if(info != null){
            log.updateText(info); // here I update second fragment TextView
        }
    }
}
```

and here's my second fragment

```
public class LogFragment extends Fragment implements LogTextUpdater{

    private TextView logView;
    private UiFragment fragment;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        fragment = new UiFragment();
        fragment.log = this; // register 
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_log, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        logView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textLog);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateText(Information info) {
        logView.setText(info.getName() + " " + info.getCity());
    }
}
```

Here's my `MainActivity`

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
 private PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        initialisePaging();
    }

    private void initialisePaging() {
        List<Fragment> fragments = new Vector<>();
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, UiFragment.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, LogFragment.class.getName()));
        mPagerAdapter = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);
        ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        pager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
    }
}
```

and here's my error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
            at carproject.hfad.com.carproject.UiFragment.setInformationObject(UiFragment.java:289)
            at carproject.hfad.com.carproject.UiFragment.sendCommand(UiFragment.java:313)
            at carproject.hfad.com.carproject.UiFragment.access$300(UiFragment.java:39)
            at carproject.hfad.com.carproject.UiFragment$1.onClick(UiFragment.java:125)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4654)
            at android.widget.CompoundButton.performClick(CompoundButton.java:104)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19438)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

After debug I found that `log is null!` but why? I register interface in LogFragment `fragment.log = this; // register`

Comment: Fragment to Fragment communication done with the help of hosting activity. Have callbacks to the hosting activity and then you can pass data to second fragment and update ui there

Answer (score 1):

`Fragment` to `fragment` communication is not allowed. Please check the [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html). The key sentence:

> Often you will want one Fragment to communicate with another, for example to change the content based on a user event. All Fragment-to-Fragment communication is done through the associated Activity. Two Fragments should never communicate directly.

### What you should do

Your `MainActivity` should implement the `LogTextUpdater`. Then in the `updateText` method you should find the `LogFragment` and pass the `Information` to it.